# NSTextView binding for complete: broken on macOS 10.12?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextview

I've got an `NSTextView` subclass (Obj-C) that implements completion through the standard mechanism (implementing `completionsForPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:` and `rangeForUserCompletion`, etc.).  In the past, completion was invoked automatically by AppKit with either of two user actions: pressing command-. (command-period), or pressing esc (escape).  I have just switched to a new "late 2016" MacBook Pro, and simultaneously upgraded from 10.11 to 10.12.  Code completion no longer works in my app.  I just get a call to `NSBeep()` from deep in the responder chain, when nobody responds to those keypresses.  `NSTextView`'s `complete:` method is never hit (says the debugger).

I suspect that this is because of a change Apple made.  I notice that the doc for `complete:` (at https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstextview/1449359-complete?language=objc) has changed; it used to say that `complete:` was triggered by `esc`, but now it says it is triggered by `F5` (which also does not seem to work, on my machine, but function key mappings are always bizarre and incomprehensible, so who knows on that).

I did a little sleuthing by overriding `doCommandForSelector:` to just print the selector that AppKit is trying, and then calling super.  As it turns out, pressing `esc` now causes `doCommandForSelector:` to be called with `cancelOperation:` and `cancel:`, and pressing command-. now causes `cancel:`.  That makes some sense, since those keys are used to cancel out of panels, etc., but there is no panel involved here, no operation to cancel out of, etc.

My question is: what is the best way for me to simply get the old behavior back?  On 10.12 and later, in other words, I still want both `esc` and command-. to invoke `complete:` in my app.  I found Apple's doc on changing key bindings through a plist file, but that doesn't seem likely to be the right way to do it.  Maybe I should do a `keyDown:` override, but I thought those were discouraged because of complications regarding coalescing of key events, interpretation of key codes on international keyboards, etc.; my understanding is that that is generally too low a point to intervene in event processing.  Instead, I think I am supposed to modify the behavior of `interpretKeyEvents:` somehow, to bind the keys I want to `complete:`, but I can't figure out how to do that in code.

Comment: Regarding `keyDown:` not being the right way to do this, note e.g. Apple's doc (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html) where it says "It can extract the event object’s characters using the characters method of `NSEvent` and interpret these to see if they are associated with a known keyboard action. If they are, it invokes the appropriate action method in itself or a superview. This approach is discouraged."

Comment: I imagine that they changed the function key mappings because of the touch bar that replaced the function keys. Have you seen this document (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextEditing/TextEditing.html)? The "Intercepting Key Events" section talks about using a delegate to capture input and uses textView:doCommandBySelector: to perform stuff for the text view.

Comment: Yep, I know that doc.  What it doesn't seem to explain is how an application can change the key bindings.  I.e., how can I make it so that within my app escape translates into a call to `complete:`, as it used to, rather than into a call to `cancel:`?  There's a mention of how the user can define custom key bindings with a plist in their ~/Library folder, but I don't see anything about changing the bindings within a particular app in code.  Which seems like a bizarre oversight.

Comment: The default key binding is option-Escape and also F5.

Comment: @Willeke, didn't used to be; so that's a policy change as of 10.12, I take it?  Well, as explained in the question, I want escape and command-period to bind to complete:, as they used to.

Comment: Yeah this is one of those areas that for some reason Apple seems to have ignored. I think the best thing would be overriding keyDown: and making it as noninvasive as possible. The problem with the pList in ~/Library is I think it's global, not specific to your app. So either that, overriding keyDown:, using delegation or implementing your own key binding system (since Apple doesn't support dynamic key binding) but that could be a pain to code. I ran into this problem on my app, which required a mode to disable all but 6 keys + keyboard shortcuts. I ended up overriding keyDown:.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer that overrides `keyDown:` to make the key bindings work.  As mentioned in the question, though, I'm not sure that this is the correct/recommended way to do things.

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSString *chars = [event charactersIgnoringModifiers];
    NSEventModifierFlags flags = [event modifierFlags] & NSEventModifierFlagDeviceIndependentFlagsMask;

    if ([chars length] == 1)
    {
        unichar keyChar = [chars characterAtIndex:0];

        if ((keyChar == 0x1B) && (flags == 0))
        {
            // escape key pressed
            [self doCommandBySelector:@selector(complete:)];
            return;
        }
        if ((keyChar == '.') && (flags == NSEventModifierFlagCommand))
        {
            // command-. pressed
            [self doCommandBySelector:@selector(complete:)];
            return;
        }
    }

    [super keyDown:event];
}
```

If somebody gives a better answer, I'll be happy to choose it.

Comment: Note that even this no longer suffices to make command-. work, although it continues to work for esc (on Catalina).

Answer (score 0):

In Sierra, the key combination 'opt-esc' has replaced 'esc' as the standard binding for `complete:`. As you have observed, the unmodified 'esc' is now bound to `cancelOperation:`. For my apps, I'm documenting the new behaviour rather than overiding it as I suspect Apple has its reasons for making such an annoying change.